# How to set workspace in eclipse to a directory that has space in it?

Tags: eclipse

In my code, i get the workspace directory and then create a temporary file in it. However, my workspace directory has space in it:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\F1QB\Workspace
```

When my code reads this, it throws an error saying that it cannot find the directory. Now, i read that i should use a directory with no spaces in it. But, since i am working on my company's machine, I don't have admin access. So, this is the only directory i can use.

I tried switch workspace option and gave %20 instead of the space. But, eclipse throws an error on restart. It says:

```
 The folder C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\F1QB\.metadata is read only.
```

Is there any workaround for this problem? Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `c:\Docume~1\F1QB\Workspace` that usually works for long file and directory names.